# Flutter/Dart - How to use Return Data from Http Post in a Conditional to avoid Duplicate upload?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, conditional-statements

Upon clicking a `FlatButton` an audio file is uploaded to a directory on my server, renamed and the new path/name is saved to a PHP/mySQL database. I'd like to prevent the button from uploading the same file twice. But I can't use a mySQL query in a conditional as the name of the file has been changed before insertion into the database. So I've got the `oldname` of the file extracted from the response.body upon a successful 200 upload, but not sure how to get the `oldname` back to the button.

Here's the code for the FlatButton:

```
child: FlatButton(
        
                onPressed: () {
                
                    uploadAudio(
                        currentuserid: socialProvider.currentuserid,
                        filepath: _current.path);
                },          
              ),
```

And here's the uploadAudio method which returns a response from the MySQL query;

```
String oldname;

Future<String> uploadAudio({String currentuserid, String filepath}) async {

  final serverurl = "http://example.com/audiopostsfile.php";    
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverurl));
  request.fields['userid'] = currentuserid;    

  var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("audio", filepath,
      contentType: MediaType("audio", "mp4"));
        request.files.add(multiPartFile);
        request.send().then((result) async {
          http.Response.fromStream(result).then((response) {
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                  String serverResponse = response.body;
                  const start = "gxz";
                  const end = "zxg";
                  final startIndex = serverResponse.indexOf(start);
                  final endIndex = serverResponse.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);
                  oldname = serverResponse.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
                }
          });
   });
    return oldname;
  }
```

Any ideas how I can do this and prevent a duplicate upload?

Comment: How about making a boolean and switch it true/false before/after clicking on upload button, and then inside your click callback check if this boolean is true or false, example : if(!fileIsUploade) make the boolean true, upload the file, make it back false.

Comment: The problem is I need confirmation from the server that the file was successfully uploaded. I'll edit the post to include the new regex I'm using with the response.body.

Comment: You are returning `oldname` to the `FlatButton`s `onPressed`. Inside `onPressed` you can do `String oldname = await uploadAudio( .. )`

Comment: Where would I put that? Any chance of some example code?

Comment: inside `FlatButton`s `onPressed` instead of only calling `uploadAudio` you can assign the value returned by it to some variable like :  `onPressed: () { String oldname = await uploadAudio( currentuserid: socialProvider.currentuserid,filepath: _current.path); }`

Comment: I tried that and got a null when I tried to print the return: IE:  print(oldname);

Comment: Looks like the oldname variable isn't returning the string. I tried testname = "testname"; before the return testname; and got the "testname" string. But I don't know how to get the oldname = serverResponse.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex); into the return.

Answer (score 0):

How about once the file is successfully uploaded to the server, you compute the checksum of the file and return that back.  Before determining to enable the button and send the file to server, you can check to see if the checksum of the file you want to upload is different than the one that the server response.  You can cache a list of these checksum to check against.  If not then you can assume that the user want to override the old upload.

Comment: I guess my real question is how do I return the info - whether that be the file's name or checksum so that I can use it in a conditional for the button?