# Flutter/Dart - Why does my Future return Null?

Tags: flutter, dart, scope, return, future

I want to return a string extracted from the response.body of an Http Post. But my code returns null instead of the string. The string `oldname` will print just fine if I put it in the scope of `request.send()` but I need it to be returned when calling the `uploadAudio` method. What am I doing wrong?

```
Future<String> uploadAudio({String currentuserid, String filepath}) async {

  String oldname; 
  final serverurl = "http://example.com/audiofile.php";

  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverurl));
  request.fields['userid'] = currentuserid;    

  var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("audio", filepath,
      contentType: MediaType("audio", "mp4"));
        request.files.add(multiPartFile);
        request.send().then((result) async {
          http.Response.fromStream(result).then((response) {
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                  String serverResponse = response.body;
                  const start = "gxz";
                  const end = "zxg";
                  final startIndex = serverResponse.indexOf(start);
                  final endIndex = serverResponse.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);
                  oldname = serverResponse.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
                }
          });
   });
    print oldname;
    return oldname;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from the fact you are mixing the use of `await` and `then()`. I will recommend you are staying with one concept in general.

I have rewritten your code so it is now using `await` everywhere (also cleaned it a little bit up):

```
Future<String> uploadAudio({String currentuserid, String filepath}) async {
  const serverurl = "http://example.com/audiofile.php";

  final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverurl))
    ..fields['userid'] = currentuserid;

  final multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("audio", filepath,
      contentType: MediaType("audio", "mp4"));

  request.files.add(multiPartFile);

  final response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());
  String oldname;

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final serverResponse = response.body;
    const start = "gxz";
    const end = "zxg";
    final startIndex = serverResponse.indexOf(start);
    final endIndex = serverResponse.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);
    oldname = serverResponse.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
  }

  print(oldname);
  return oldname;
}
```

As you can see, the code are much easier to read now without all that nested `then()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Await your futures:

```
Future<String> uploadAudio({String currentuserid, String filepath}) async {

  String oldname; 
  final serverurl = "http://example.com/audiofile.php";

  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverurl));
  request.fields['userid'] = currentuserid;    

  var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("audio", filepath,
      contentType: MediaType("audio", "mp4"));
        request.files.add(multiPartFile);
        await request.send().then((result) async {
          await http.Response.fromStream(result).then((response) {
                if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                  String serverResponse = response.body;
                  const start = "gxz";
                  const end = "zxg";
                  final startIndex = serverResponse.indexOf(start);
                  final endIndex = serverResponse.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);
                  oldname = serverResponse.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
                }
          });
   });
    print(oldname);
    return oldname;
  }
```

Comment: If you are already using `await` you should properly rewrite the code so it does not use `then()`.

Comment: Your answer worked well HBS but I could only choose one and the other provided a bit more help. However, I've got a similar question here which you could probably answer with pretty much the same solution and help to boost your points. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63191309/flutter-dart-how-to-use-return-data-from-http-post-in-a-conditional-to-avoid-d